# wxWidgets connect() not recognizing event type

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to connect a wxListCtrl event to a function in C++, and it should be straightforward. Generally using Connect() works, but for one reason or another, it isn't recognizing the event name (EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED). I've included wx/listctrl.h, and even checked to make sure the event is listed (it is; not in listctrl, but in listbase which is included in listctrl).

Here is the problem line:

```
parent->Connect (ID_Objects, wxEVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, (wxObjectEventFunction) &Editor::objectSelected);
```

The specific error is that identifier "wxEVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED" is undefined. The parent is a wxFrame.

In other places, I've used the same syntax but with a different event type and it worked fine.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED
```

Comment: @DireMuffin Easiest way to do, when it says it is undefined, is to look into source files. wxWidgets has in documentation described events for EventTable. Event for Connect are sometimes different and undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `<wx/listctrl.h>` is included in the file that contains `parent->Connect (ID_Objects, wxEVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, ...`